# What makes GraalVM Native Image run so lightning fast?

Tags: graalvm

What makes GraalVM Native Image run so lightning fast for so many different programming languages?

Nathan Aw (Singapore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this GraalVM [post](https://medium.com/graalvm/improving-performance-of-graalvm-native-images-with-profile-guided-optimizations-9c431a834edb) which reminds about the use cases relative to native compilation.

Additionaly, it details the PGO (Profile Guided Optimization) feature to optimize even further...